# setting different background color for each row power bi

Tags: powerbi

I created this matrix and I set its value on rows to have this visual :
[image]

And I want to change the background color of each row according to my customer canvas like this: [image]

Is it possible to do that ? bacause I tried formatting condition but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Add a column with color id to your source table. Say, 1, 2, 3, 4 will be respectively green, yellow, red, blue. Be sure that the color id is a number.

[image]

Display your data with table visual. Then, add conditional formatting to each column.

[image]

Set it up in this way:

[image]

Fields 1-4 enter exactly as they are shown above. I think these settings are self explanatory. Fields 5-6 are up to you. Repeat the row conditional formatting for every column. And you are done:

[image]

Here is a sample code to reproduce the source table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUUosKMhJVYrViVYyAvKSEvOAEMw1BnKTM1KLiirBXBMgNyW1PAkiEAsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "ColorID"}, {"Column2", "Category"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: This is solution is more specific to tables or matrix Values Field. But you cannot apply this to the matrix rows and columns field.

Comment: @KhurramArshad please ask a new question explaining what you would like to achieve. Note that I cannot see your desired results that you have on mind.